# FileNotFoundException while subscribing to event in MarshalByRefObject

Tags: appdomain, filenotfoundexception, marshalbyrefobject

I have application wich uses AppDomains. From main application A (it doesn't have assembly with B loaded) i create some form B, then give an object to that form.
Then i'm trying to do like this someObject.eventName += method, NotFoundException occures whis message "File or assembly name '', or one of its dependencies, was not found".
someObject.Item = value doesn't give any exceptions.

DataWrited del = new DataWrited(_logger_DataWrited); // no exceptions

_logger.DataWrited = del; // gives the same Exception as +=

Ofc all Asseblies are in base folder and are accecible

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Problem solved.I tried to use in A method, which was implemented in B, ofc Exception generated.